# is there a way to change Text values automatically with Animation?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a loading screen where I want to show a text changing its value automatically with an animation.

I have my logo rotating indefinitely without any button action

```
//logo
                    Image("reny")
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotateDegree))
                        .onAppear(perform: {
                                 withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 4).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                                     self.rotateDegree = 360
                                 }
                             })
```

I assumed it was possible to do the same for a text using a string array but it doesn't work

```
@State var texts = ["Find the Apartment you like", "send an application", "we'll approve you in secs baby!"]
    @State var textIndex : Int = 0
```

```
//introduction text
                    Text(texts[textIndex]).bold()
                        .font(.title)
                        .onAppear(perform: {
                            withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 2).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                                textIndex += 1
                            }
                             })
```

does anybody know how to change the value of a text with an animation automatically?

my intention is to show how to use the app during this loading time.

Comment: Which do you want? Transitions and Animations are two different things. Transitions deal with exchanging one view for another, where animations deal with a change within one view.

Comment: animation I guess, I just want the text value to change and loop based on the arrays value

Comment: The code is working fine here. What do you expect to happen vs. what is happening. Also, to read;;y helps to produce a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I had to create a view to plug this into, and you may be doing something different, but are not showing it. This goes along with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible approach - just to replace Text depending on index and continuously change index after appear.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

Main part:

```
private func next() {
    var next = textIndex + 1
    if next == texts.count {
        next = 0
    }
    withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 2)) {
        textIndex = next
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
        self.next()
    }
}
```

and text itself

```
Text(texts[textIndex]).bold()
    .font(.title).id(textIndex)
    .onAppear(perform: {
        next()
    })
```

[Test module on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestContinuousTextAnimation.swift)